# I do not have a valid raster for parameterization + texturing from registered rasters

Tags: meshlab

This is my first time using Meshlab so I don't really know my way around the software or how to troubleshoot myself. Thought I would post in here in the hope that someone can help/point me in the right direction. I am using the software for a university project and my tutor shared the following tutorial video with me:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDHJM6nAKtc&t=570s

I have followed all of the steps but when I get to apply the texture I get an error message. To apply the texture I take these steps:

Filters>Textures>Parameterization + texturing from registered rasters

In the dialogue box that popped up, I changed 'Texture Size' from the default 1024 to 2048

After clicking apply the following error message pops up:

*"Failure of filter : 'Parameterization + texturing from registered rasters'
You need to have at least one valid raster layer in your project, to apply this filter"*

I don't know what this means or how to get around it!

I would really appreciate it if someone can help get around this issue and help me learn what went wrong!

Thanks very much in advance,

Chris

**Edit**

Screenshots of the process from start to error:

[image: Step 1: Open Project]

[image: Step 2: Open Project]

[image: Step 3: Import Mesh]

[image: Step 4: Import Mesh]

[image: Dense Mesh of a piece of coral]

[image: Step 5: Poisson Mesh]

[image: Step 6: Change reconstruction depth from 8 to 9]

[image: Poisson Mesh created]

[image: Step 9: Delete unneccessary faces]

[image: Step 8: Vertex Colour Filling- White]

[image: Step 9: Parameterization + texturing from registered rasters]

[image: Step 10: Change texture size to 2048]

[image: Error Message]

Comment: It might be useful to provide some screenshots that go with the steps you have outlined.  Also, any details about the model or texture(s) would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Hopefully, the screenshots are useful As I'm not sure where I'm going wrong I thought best to show the process from the start (apologies if it seems a bit overkill).

For context, the info imported was from Colmap.

Answer (score 0):

Your "Bundler.out.list.txt" file is empty (0 bytes). Therefore, MeshLab never imports any of the images (i.e. rasters) and thus the error message.

*Why is my Bundler.out.list.txt" file empty?*

When you exported your *dense* model from Colab, there were no cameras "loaded" (...likely you chose to view the *dense* point cloud created after the Fusion reconstruction step, which unloaded the cameras...)

*What to do?*

Just import your *sparse* model into Colab, and when you see your cameras loaded, export a Bundler model. This will create the correct "Bundler.out.list.txt" file to use with MeshLab.